# Blazor Javascript isolation with NPM dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to use the new Blazor [Javascript isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-javascript-isolation-and-object-references) feature. I'm importing my own JS file as per the example `ExampleJsInterop.cs`. It works until I try to import an NPM module from within my script. In my package.json I have set up a dependency on interactjs, and in my script I have added `import interact from 'interactjs';` at the top.

I'm getting a `Failed to resolve module specifier "interactjs"` error. I'm not sure how to get past that.

Previously I was using Webpack to bundle my script and dependencies together into a single file that is added into my index.html as a  tag. This was working fine, but I'm not sure how to continue using NPM packages with JS isolation.

Thanks!

Comment: Blazor’s JavaScript isolation does not do any bundling to resolve dependencies from npm. You will still have to do that separately if you want to use npm dependencies or more complex things at build time.

Comment: Check your js file extension, the js file extension should be '.js', instead of '.cs'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I left this question open for almost a year!

I ended up solving it using Snowpack to bundle the NPM package into the Blazor wwwroot folder. Credit goes to this article for pointing me in the right direction: https://nbarraud.github.io/js-in-blazor.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I've just finished solving a similar issue.
The npm files are installed to the hidden node_modules folder. This isn't available to your script when you are running your app, unless you do something to make it available. however, even if you copied the interactjs file into your scripts folder it would still not work if it was an npm file. Those are meant to run in nodejs not a browser. So you would still need to use your bundler. I tried webpack, but had some issues with certain files so ended up with snowpack instead. I just finished a bunch of articles on javascript interop - [part 4 deals with npm](http://littlewolfsolutions.com/blog/javascript-interop-in-blazor-web-assembly-part-4-using-npm-in-blazor/)

Comment: Thank you but your article is an uncredited rewriting of https://nbarraud.github.io/js-in-blazor.html which helped me solve the problem eventually.